# FLASH AS3 SOUND_COMPLETE firing at start of sound

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The gotoAndStop() method is called on the sound being loaded, the trace is fired when the sound has finished. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

here is my code:

```
 import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var soundReq:URLRequest = new 
URLRequest("testmp3.mp3");
sound.load(soundReq);
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundPlay);
function soundPlay(event:Event):void
{   
    var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
    soundChannel = sound.play();
    soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundComplete);
}
function soundComplete(event:Event):void
{
    trace("The sound has finished playing.");

    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you're mistaken.

`Event.COMPLETE` called when sound file load completed.

```
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundPlay);
```

`Event.SOUND_COMPLETE` called when sound playback ended.

```
soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundComplete);
```

refer a following code.

---

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
var soundReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("testmp3.mp3");
sound.load(soundReq);
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundFileLoaded);
function soundFileLoaded(event:Event):void
{   
    trace("sound file loaded!");

    gotoAndStop(3);
    var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
    soundChannel = sound.play();
    soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundPlaybackEnded);
}
function soundPlaybackEnded(event:Event):void
{
    trace("sound playback ended");
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you said, but I want to gotoAndStop(3) after the sound is finished playing, not finished loading. Maybe I am missing something? The frame change is happening when the sound is loaded, and I do not want it to.

Comment: I marked as correct due to the good information, however to fix the issue I needed to add a stop(); after the Event.Complete method, this stopped the script after the load was called, then called the sound_complete correctly.